# Customize UIImagePickerController Confirmation View

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

With the UIImagePickerController, there are 2 views:

1. The first has the camera controls where you take the photo. I want
   to keep this one the same.
2. The second shows a preview of the photo,
       with a retake and use photo button.

I want to customize just this view so people can use their finger to draw on the photo. Is this doable, or do I have to completely build my own image picker?

Comment: You have to create your own image picker

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36704374/3472073 here is an example how to create custom picker