# Perform "use photo" button on custom image picker overlay

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am creating fully custom overlay for image picker controller. First stage is easy: I am get first view with record/take a shot button, which call `takePicture()` method.

Next stage is change UI to "Retake" or "Use photo" which is also with my own design. "Retake" probably can be imitated by calling `presentViewController` again. How should I imitate "Use photo" button?

Comment: Is this happening because when takePhoto() method called, [self.imagePickerController takePicture] code works and it calls didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo ? so you get chance to change your UI text , Right ?

Comment: Well. I am feel stupid with that question and more stupid with starting bounty. The methods `takePicture` and `stopVideoCapture` did not work as I expected. They calls `imagePickerController(_, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo)` so the simple answer of @avinash-dadhich is correct. My mistake was that app crashes before that method call or something like that. Sorry for confusing.

Answer (score 8):

You can easily inherit `UIImagePickerController`

**Objective-C**

```
@interface CameraViewController : UIImagePickerController

@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSInteger state; // 0 - auto 1 - on 2 - off

@end

@implementation CameraViewController

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if (!TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR) {
            self.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            self.showsCameraControls = NO;
            self.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
        } else {
            self.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        }
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        self.allowsEditing = NO;
        self.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(orientationChanged)
                                                     name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                                   object:nil];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

@end
```

Then override `viewDidLoad` and customize UI to your needs by creating `UIView` object and set it to `self.cameraOverlayView`. In my example it is custom flash button.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIButton *changeFlashButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    changeFlashButton.frame = CGRectMake(70, 27, 40, 40);
    [changeFlashButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flash_auto"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
    changeFlashButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
    [changeFlashButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeFlashValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view addSubview:changeFlashButton];
    if (!TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR) {
        self.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
        changeFlashButton.alpha = [[self class] isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice:self.cameraDevice];
        self.cameraOverlayView = view;
    }
}

- (void)changeFlashValue:(UIButton*)aSwitch {
    if (self.state == 0) { //auto - on
        self.state = 1;
        [self.flashSwitch setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flash_on"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn;
        return;
    }
    if (self.state == 1) { //on - off
        self.state = 2;
        [self.flashSwitch setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flash_off"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
        return;
    }
    if (self.state == 2) { //off - auto
        self.state = 0;
        [self.flashSwitch setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flash_auto"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
        return;
    }
}
```

Your controls of camera could be like this
[image: from left-to-right: flash, take picture, front/rear camera, photo-gallery]

Please pay attentions that for not showing to user "Retake" and "Use photo" buttons you need to set `allowsEditing` to false

And actually the same for **Swift 2.2+**

```
class CameraViewController: UIImagePickerController {

    var state: Int?

    init() {
        super.init(navigationBarClass: nil, toolbarClass: nil)
        #if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && (os(iOS) || os(watchOS) || os(tvOS)) // any simulator
            self.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        #else
            self.sourceType = .Camera
            self.showsCameraControls = false
            self.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
        #endif

        self.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
        self.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve
        self.allowsEditing = false
        self.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerControllerMediaType]
        UIDevice.currentDevice().beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(orientationChanged), name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    // strange compiler requirements
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    func orientationChanged() {
        // update to the new orientation
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let view: UIView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        var changeFlashButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        changeFlashButton.frame = CGRectMake(70, 27, 40, 40)
        changeFlashButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "flash_auto"), forState: .Normal)
        self.cameraFlashMode = .Auto
        changeFlashButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
        changeFlashButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeFlashValue(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(changeFlashButton)
        #if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && (os(iOS) || os(watchOS) || os(tvOS)) // any simulator
        #else
            self.cameraFlashMode = .Auto
            changeFlashButton.alpha = UIImagePickerController.isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice(self.cameraDevice) ? 1 : 0
        #endif
    }

    func changeFlashValue(aSwitch: UIButton) {
        if self.state == 0 {
            // auto - on
            self.state = 1
            self.flashSwitch.setImage(UIImage.imageNamed("flash_on"), forState: .Normal)
            self.cameraFlashMode = .On
            return
        }
        if self.state == 1 {
            // on - off
            self.state = 2
            self.flashSwitch.setImage(UIImage.imageNamed("flash_off"), forState: .Normal)
            self.cameraFlashMode = .Off
            return
        }
        if self.state == 2 {
            // off - auto
            self.state = 0
            self.flashSwitch.setImage(UIImage.imageNamed("flash_auto"), forState: .Normal)
            self.cameraFlashMode = .Auto
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can imitate use photo by presenting a view controller that gives user option to edit the taken image and adding save and cancel button as well. How does that sound?

Comment: I can't get actual image or video until user press "Use photo" button. When he pressed my view controller gets all necessary info. May be I can get it earlier somewhere.